# Java - How do I sandbox ScriptEngineManager?

Tags: java, security, scriptengine

I can easily execute JavaScript using the built-in `ScriptEngineManager`. However, it gives full permission to JavaScript, which is a big problem for me.

### It allows dangerous commands such as:

- `javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello, Server!");`
- `java.lang.System.exit(0);`

How do I limit the availability of Java functions in the Javascript Engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sandbox by default blocks access to all Java classes.

```
NashornSandbox sandbox = NashornSandboxes.create();
sandbox.allow(File.class);  
sandbox.eval("var File = Java.type('java.io.File'); File;")
```

[delight-nashorn-sandbox](https://github.com/javadelight/delight-nashorn-sandbox)

Comment: Thanks! This put me in the right direction. Unfortunately, sandbox.disallow() doesn't block the class if accessed from a function (`object.getDangerousManager().stop()`). How would I prevent the function from obtaining a blocked class?